# Migrating Pixture Reloaded theme to drupal 7.x

Tags: 7, theming, migrations

I'm migrating a drupal6 site to Drupal 7 which uses [Pixture Reloaded](https://www.drupal.org/project/pixture_reloaded) as its default theme. In Drupal 6, Pixture Reloaded was standalong theme which required no base theme but now I see that for Drupal 7 versions, its a subtheme of Adaptivetheme.

How do I migrate my old theme to new Pixture reloaded for Drupal 7? Is there a upgrade path for the migration?? I have now added and enabled both Adaptive and Pixture reloaded theme and have set the default theme to Pixture relaoded. As expected, most of the views, panels and blocks are broken but pages look fine.

Any pointers for the migration/upgrade would be helpful.